# ¿Como solucionar ciclo de carga infinito en un visor de reportes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, aspx, rdlc

estoy tratando de crear un reporte web en una pagina .aspx, la plantilla del reporte es un archivo .rdlc. cuando corro la aplicación, lleno una gráfica de barras con el mismo Datasource que uso para el reporte, sin embargo mi reporte se queda ciclado en cargando volviendo a llamar a la aplicación como si estuviera actualizando la pagina:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código con el que lleno el reporte es el siguiente:

```
DataTable datos = new DataTable();
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OCEntities"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from Vista_ReporteCompras ", con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
                da.Fill(datos);
            }
            visor.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            visor.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Plantilla.rdlc");
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("Datos", datos);
            visor.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            visor.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
            cargar = false;
```

¿Tienen una idea de como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a esta **[respuesta en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11781339/4092887)**, es posible que su error se deba a que no ha implementado el `PostBack` en su código fuente.

Ejemplo:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Report data source code...
        myReport.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
}
```